# Read NRC like &amp; in wxString

Tags: c++, html, parsing, wxwidgets

I am trying to read a xml-file with wxWidgets. Normally the text in the file is fully parsed.
So that `&amp;` becomes `&` etc.

If i decode some text because it's base64 still all escapes are fully parsed. Now i want a string like `wxT("&amp")` also to show up as `"&"`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You search the string for the `"&amp;"` and replace it with `"&"`.

If using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) this can be done with the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) methods.

Comment: It is not that simple. I want all NRC to be parsed like &lt; and &#2245;

Comment: @Pookie79 How about [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) then?

Comment: I'll try that altough regex arn't realy my thing... Tanks

Comment: It seems the best approach is using `wxHtmlEntitiesParser::Parse(wxString)`

I copied that code because i needed something extra in it but it does the trick.